# logstash mongo Db connection issue

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, configuration, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am unable to push data to `mongo Db` using `logstash`
My config file looks like:-

```
input {
  file {
    type => "log"
    path => "d:\logs\*.txt"

  }
}

output {
  mongodb {
    database => "abhi1"    
    collection => "plain" 
    uri => "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017" 
  } 
}
```

command used for executing configuration file is `logstash -f ./conf/demo.conf`

ERROR  :-

```
[2015-09-08T16:26:04.883000 #4528] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | COMMAND | namespace=a
in.$cmd selector={:ismaster=>1} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 project=nil | runtime
46.9999ms
```

hoping to get a workaround soon. thanks

Comment: Your message is just the normal mongodb heartbeat output which is written in debug mode. You may ignore it. Try setting `output { stdout { } }` to see if there are incoming messages. It is also a good idea to delete logstash's sincedb files in order to avoid reparsing issues.

Comment: Thanks Hurb for a quick reply...but using stdout is leaving me with this message:-----------------





D:\logstash-1.5.4\bin>logstash -f ./conf/demo.conf
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
Logstash startup completed

Comment: hello hurb I tried using Verbose execution and this is the output I m getting.please help---------------------------------------- D:\logstash-1.5.4\bin>logstash -v -f ./conf/demo.conf io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated ←[32mRegistering file input {:path=>["d:\\logs\*.txt"], :level=>:info}←[0m ←[32mNo sincedb_path set, generating one based on the file path {:sincedb_path=> "C:\\Users\\abhishek_kumar/.sincedb_19458b6cb8ec891d77c2daf60c69dd 9c", :path=>["d:\\logs\*.txt"], :level=>:info}←[0m ←[32mPipeline started {:level=>:info}←[0m Logstash startup completed –

Comment: Did you delete all `.sincedb` files in `C:\Users\abhishek_kumar\ ` ? Are there new log messages in `D:\logs\*.txt`? Try setting `start_position => "beginning"`inside your file input.

Comment: yes hurb , I deleted all the sincedb files from the directory before executing logstash command.but still no luck with the output. I am using this conf script :----------------------------------------



input {
  file {
    start_position => "beginning"
    type => "log"
    path => "d:\logs\*.txt"
    
  }
}

output {
file {
    path => "d:\abhi.txt"} }

Comment: And yes , there are new log messages in my folder(D:\logs\*.txt). please help.